# Delete Oracle with join tables

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has three columns ( primary key) and I need a delete sentece that allows me to remove the elements I don't need , using a join with the this table and other table, I've tried two delete sentences but they are not working as expected:

**First One**: This one gets the values I dont need and they are removed from table A, but the issue here is it deletes the values from Table B and C too and those rows can't be removed

```
DELETE
FROM
  (SELECT A.*
  FROM TABLE_A A
  JOIN TABLE_B B
  ON A.CODE  =B.CODE
  JOIN TABLE_C C
  ON B.PRODUCT           =C.PRODUCT           
  WHERE B.VALUE       >10000
  AND C.RANGE NOT  IN (4006, 4005, 4004, 4003, 4002, 4001)
  );
```

**Second One:**The problem with this one is that it removes all the rows from table A, but if I test the query ( select) it returns 5 rows, the ones that should be removed.

```
DELETE
FROM A WHERE EXIST
  (SELECT A.*
  FROM TABLE_A A
  JOIN TABLE_B B
  ON A.CODE  =B.CODE
  JOIN TABLE_C C
  ON B.PRODUCT           =C.PRODUCT   
  WHERE B.VALUE       >10000
  AND C.RANGE NOT  IN (4006, 4005, 4004, 4003, 4002, 4001)
  );
```

So has anyone any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first one will delete matched rows across the joins, the second one will delete all rows when there `EXISTS` any one matched row as you are not correlating the deleted rows to the sub-query.

You can perform this correlation using the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bea7ba/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a ( id, code ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b ( id, code, product, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 10001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 10001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 1,  9999 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_c ( id, product, range ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 4001 FROM DUAL;

DELETE
FROM table_A
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT A.ROWID
  FROM   TABLE_A A
         JOIN TABLE_B B
         ON A.CODE    = B.CODE
         JOIN TABLE_C C
         ON B.PRODUCT = C.PRODUCT   
  WHERE  B.VALUE >10000
  AND    C.RANGE NOT  IN (4006, 4005, 4004, 4003, 4002, 4001)
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bea7ba/1/0)**:

```
| ID | CODE |
|----|------|
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bea7ba/1/1)**:

```
| ID | CODE | PRODUCT | VALUE |
|----|------|---------|-------|
|  1 |    1 |       1 | 10001 |
|  2 |    2 |       2 | 10001 |
|  3 |    3 |       1 |  9999 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_c
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bea7ba/1/2)**:

```
| ID | PRODUCT | RANGE |
|----|---------|-------|
|  1 |       1 |  1001 |
|  2 |       2 |  4001 |
```